# How to create a full window of a 30 days on a pandas dataframe with groupby if some days are missing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Data       type   state   price

2021-01-01 CHR     NSW     1.2
2021-01-01 CHR     VIC     8
2021-01-04 Kia     NSW     2
2021-01-05 CHR     NSW     2
```

I applied the below:

`df_daily_grouped = df_daily.groupby(['type','state])`

the output is the below for CHR:

```
Data       type   state   price

2021-01-01 CHR     NSW     1.2
2021-01-04 CHR     NSW     2
2021-01-05 CHR     NSW     2
2021-01-01 CHR     VIC     8
```

As seen above, the dates of `"2021-01-02"` and `"2021-01-03"` for CHR in  NSW are missing. I want the below output:

```
Data       type   state   price

2021-01-01 CHR     NSW     1.2
2021-01-02 CHR     NSW     Nan
2021-01-03 CHR     NSW     Nan
2021-01-04 CHR     NSW     2
2021-01-05 CHR     NSW     2
2021-01-01 CHR     VIC     8
2021-01-02 CHR     VIC     Nan
2021-01-03 CHR     VIC     Nan
2021-01-04 CHR     VIC     Nan
2021-01-05 CHR     VIC     Nan
```

Comment: two dataframes as the output?

Comment: The output should be a combination of all. The above output is after groupby

Comment: I feel something is missing from your explanation. kindly share the sample dataframe, and the expected output dataframe? so, a before and an after? so it is clear what you want

Comment: @sammywemmy please see the updated explanation

Comment: The sample data is different from your actual data. Test @wwnde's answer on the sample data and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'])#Coerce Data to datetime
df1=(df.groupby(['type','state'])['Data'].apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(min(df.Data), max(df.Data),freq='D')))
     .reset_index().drop('Data',1).rename(columns={'level_2':'Data'})#Insert missing dates by reindexing in a new df
     .merge(df, how='left', on=['type','state','Data'])#Merge new and old df
)

# Apply filter
df1[(df1['type']=='CHR')&(df1['state']=='NSW')]
```

Comment: Thanks @wwnde`*** NameError: name 'df' is not defined`.  However, `df.groupby(['type','state'])['Data']` has no error. Also, `pd.date_range(min(df.Data), max(df.Data),freq='D')' looks no error. Not sure why it's not recognizing `df`